# moq and the "as" keyword

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, as-keyword

I'm attempting to provide a mock that will help me test:

```
ClaimsPrincipal princple = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
```

However from what I can tell, the "as" keyword returns null even though I can see in the debugger Thread.CurrentPrincipal is the mock.

To test the theory I put together this short demo:

```
void Main()
{
    var userMock = new Mock<IUser>();
    userMock.Setup(w => w.UserId).Returns(1);

    var user = userMock.Object as User;

    user.Dump(); // null

}

public interface IUser
{
    int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I provide moq's for code that use the as keyword in the background?

From what I understand perhaps I need to provide a way for the proxy to cast back?

I sort of realise that this isn't possible, but wondered what people's approaches are to solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a work around, I understand I should be mocking against interfaces and shouldn't mock concrete classes, but this may have to do until I can refactor the dependencies.

The trick is to mock the concrete `class Mock<User>()` and use the `As<IUser>()` to mock the properties etc.

```
void Main()
{
    var userMock = new Mock<User>();
    userMock.As<IUser>().Setup(w => w.UserId).Returns(1);

    var user = userMock.Object as User;

    user.Dump(); // not null
}

public interface IUser
{
    int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I think I missed trying this as I've been always mocking to the interfaces in the past.

Comment: I still consider that its better to depend on IUser in your code, but solution is interesing - `As` used to *add* interface implementations to generated proxy. I didn't think about mocking class and then adding interface mock to it

Comment: Yes I agree, depending on IUser is a much better idea in this context, but for "as ClaimsPrinciple" it is 'just about ok' before I do some more good'ol refactoring in the background. :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you create mock

```
var userMock = new Mock<IUser>();
```

then Moq dynamically creates class which implements `IUser` interface. That class has no relation to other implementations of this interface (like `User` class). That's why mock object is `IUser` but it is not `User`:

```
var user = userMock.Object as User; // will be null
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey, that's what I was thinking - thanks for reaffirming that. Do you have approaches you prefer when getting around situations like this? I'm guessing really I shouldn't need to moq this and should re-factor the whole area to suit.

Comment: @AlexKey yep, you can see it by yourself in [`Mock<T>`](https://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/Mock.Generic.cs) source code. There is method `InitializeInstance` which creates proxy class

Comment: @AlexKey workaround is simple - make you code depend on interface which you are mocking instead of interface implementation

Comment: Thanks @Sergey, I just saw your comment whilst coming to the same conclusion. Thanks for your help +1 from me.